# CPU use keeps growing; is there a way to delete my unused objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm making a game in HTML5's Canvas + JavaScript. My CPU use for the tab keeps growing by a couple percent every second until it hits 50% (all of one core). I am successfully removing my objects from the array of objects, but the objects themselves seem to persist. I have tried "delete obj" and "obj = null" in a few places, but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
var falling_blocks = setInterval(add_falling_block, 1000);

...

function add_falling_block(){
    b = new Object();
    b.x = (randFromTo(0,sq) * scale) - boff;
    b.y = -scale + boff;
    b.color = "#f00";
    b.moving = true;
    b.number = f.length;
    f.push(b);
}

function draw_falling_blocks(){
    var db = new Array()
    for(i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
        var ba = f[i];
        if(ba.y < (bottom + scale)){
            ba.y += scale;
            draw_block(ba.x,ba.y,"#f00");
        }
        else if(ba.y = (bottom + scale)){
            db.push(i);
            console.log(f.length);
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < db.length; i++){
        f.splice(db[i],1);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle of it in action?

Comment: CPU usage != memory usage.  If your tab's allocated memory keeps going up, then you do have a problem with objects not getting deleted.  However, a pegged CPU indicates that your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxEjb/

Comment: @josh3736: I agree and now I am plagued by how the persistence is identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, CPU usage `!=` memory usage.  With Chrome's developer tools, it's easy to profile your application in order to locate the code which is consuming all of the CPU cycles.

Open your app, open the dev tools, and go to the Profiles tab. Click the Record button (the black circle).  It will turn red; Chrome is now recording CPU usage.  Let it record for a few seconds and click the Record button again.  You will now see CPU usage by function.

In this case, we can see that `draw_grid()` has consumed **92%** of CPU time – we've found our culprit!

I [made some changes](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/GN4bm/) to the `draw_grid` function:

```
function draw_grid(){
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    for (var i = poff; i < w; i += scale) {
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(0, i);
      c.lineTo(w, i);
      c.closePath();
      c.stroke();
    }
    for (var j = poff; j < h; j += scale) {
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(j, 0);
      c.lineTo(j, h);
      c.closePath();
      c.stroke();
    }
}
```

CPU usage never tops 5% now.

A few notes:

- I've added `beginPath()` and `closePath()` and moved `stroke()` into each loop iteration.
- I changed the size of each line from a constant 500px to use the appropriate variable.
- You only need to set `strokeStyle` once.  It remains the same unless you change it again.
- You should write `var` in your loops' initializer to restrict the variable's (`i` and `j` in this case) scope to the local function.  Otherwise, you're creating a global variable, which is a bad idea for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Thank you! Amazing answer. This is perfect. My CPU use is sitting at 1% now.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete all properties/methods of that object in addition to deleting the pointer (variable), but memory leakage has always been a problem that's plagued JavaScript.

Have you thrown in `setTimeout('',0)` anywhere to allow the processor to do some other things.

Comment: When I put that in my main game function, CPU use did grow more slowly, but it still grew to 50%/max eventually.

Comment: You may be deleting things faster than the CPU can process, try upping it to 50